# How to get access_token for V5 facebook PHP without login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I have created application by checking all the checkbox of the permission.[image]

I want to auto post to selected page. I have used the following code. When I am login to facebook then it will allow me to post to that selected page.

```
<?php
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '{APP-ID}',
            'app_secret' => '{APP-SECRET}',
        ]);
        $linkData = [
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
            'message' => 'Auto',
          ];
        try {
            $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '{access-token}');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($graphNode);
    die(); 
    ?>
```

I have got 
`{access-token}` by copying the token from the text-box nearby  "Get Token" button.I want to get this `{access-token}` when I am not logged in.Please help. I am trying from the last two days.

**I have got following errors:**

1. An access token is required to request this resource. An active
2. access token must be used to query information about the current
   user.

Comment: You can not get a user token without login. If you want to post to a page, then get a page access token, and extend it.

Comment: thank you so much @CBroe